# What localhost port is serving my app on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, python, port

I'm a newb to the Windows development environment and I have cloned a git repository for a python+javascript project I developed on my Mac (Unix). I have the environment set up and have the script running but when I open Chrome and go to localhost:5000 where it would be on my Unix environment, it's not there. How do I find the correct port where it's served up on Windows 10?

My run.py script is (the first line is for Unix use on my other machine):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from app import app
app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', debug = True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do, if I were you is identify the running process in the Task Manager and grab it's PID. From there, I would open a command prompt, and use the netstat command to get a list of all active connections:

```
netstat -ano
```

From there, simply find a line where the last column have your PID number, and you should find which port it's running on (under the Local Address column).

Alternatively, you could pipe the output of netstat to a find command with the PID for an easier time.

```
netstat -ano | find /i "$PID_NUMBER"
```

For this to work though, you'll have to be able to identify your app process in the Task Manager (you can add the "Command line" column to see how a process is launched, it might help you identify it).

Comment: There are three python processes running when I have my script running: two python.exe and one py.exe. Of those one of the python.exe consistently shows up ported to 5000, yet when I call up localhost/5000 in Chrome it says "This localhost page cannot be found." It appears that I do have the right port, but something else is wrong. This probably warrants a separate question.

Comment: Most likely, yes. Is it possible that the application is listening on port 5000, but doesn't know how to handle a response? Maybe adding a bit of logging would provide more details (if the app doesn't already have some kind of logging and/or produces debug logs).

Comment: You're likely right. This is its first flight in the Windows environment so I may be missing some pieces to help get it off the ground. Thanks!

Comment: Ah!! It was working all along. When I typed http://127.0.0.1:5000/ into Chrome it came right up. Thanks for helping confirm I was headed in the right direction...

Comment: Glad to see that you got it to work! I didn't notice that you tried localhost/5000 instead of localhost:5000, otherwise I would've noted it. Good job!

Comment: Oh geez. You're right. I did type a slash instead of colon. Ha! Well. At least it was a simple fix. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, you're welcome!